# Magento 2.4.x: Update customer data on account registration

Tags: magento2, customer-account, registration

I want to enable remote shopping assistance when a new customer account is created:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please check this link:** https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/customers/customer-accounts/manage/login-as-customer.html?lang=en

**Also please check below module must be enabled.**

```
Magento_LoginAsCustomer
Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance
Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl
Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog
Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache
Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote
Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales
```